# Can't delete something but works somewhere else. MongoDB / Python (motor)

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm using mongodb with the python module `motor`.

When I try to delete something in my function it's not working but when I try it somewhere else it works. I added a print after the delete (using `delete_one`) and it's printing.
Other actions are working well.

```
async def setup(self, guild):
    db = self.db
    await db.properties.delete_one({"guildid": guild.id})
    print(1) #this is printing but nothing gets deleted in the database.
```

Comment: Print `guild.id` content what is in it? Is it Object ID?

Comment: guild.id is an int